# Regex literal in Frege

Tags: frege

What is an unicode code for grave accent mark used to specify regex literal in Frege?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character is called *Acute Accent* and the unicode for that is `00B4`. In ubuntu, you can type that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and then type `00B4` then <kbd>space</kbd>. However you don't really have to use that if your regex literal is more than one character in which case you can just use apostrophes.

Quoting the [doc](http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/frege/java/util/Regex):

```
Regular expression literals have type Regex and are written:

 ´\b(foo|bar)\b´       -- string enclosed in grave accents
 '\w+'                 -- string with length > 1 enclosed in apostrophes
The notation with the apostrophes has been introduced because many have a hard time entering a grave accent mark on their terminal. However, it is not possible to write a regular expressions with length 1 this way, because then the literal gets interpreted as Char literal. (One can write something like '(?:X)' for a Regex that matches a single 'X').
```